# Get list of nearby places from Google Places API (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3, google-places-api

I am aware that there are similar threats already, however, the *exact* topic I am looking for seems to not have been touched.

I am a programming newby, however, I achieved to get an app running, which fetches your current location, transforms the coordinates to an address and is able to store your location data in a tableView.

Now I am looking for a way on how to fetch a list of nearby stores with the help of the Google Places API and **display them in a table view**. I could only find plenty of help on how to display POIs on a map view, however, I would only like to display those in a list (e.g. "Walmart, 1st Avenue, 1234 Waltown).

Is some friendly stranger able to help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

All the best from Germany,
Jonas

Comment: so you want only stores or all points of interest near to given user?

Comment: what do u mean by saying _display them in a list view_?

Comment: I only want stores. 

And I want them to be in a table view (excuse my wrong wording in the original question), with 2 labels per cell (name and address).

Comment: I'm trying to narrow down as to what exactly you want because u have asked two questions. The first one is finding places and the other one is displaying them in a tableview. Which one of these two have u already done?

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=google+places+&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93, you can checkout any of this repo and you will surely get good examples there

Comment: @EmilDavid - none... :(

Comment: Well, I'd recommend you start [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Lightweight Solution!

I created a google wrapper to call google near by api here : **[Google Api Helper](https://github.com/tryWabbit/Google-Api-Helper)**

```
var input = GInput()
input.keyword = "Restaurants"
input.radius = 20000
var location = GLocation()
location.latitude = 26.273178
location.longitude = 73.009545
input.destinationCoordinate = location
GoogleApi.shared.callApi(.nearBy, input: input) { (response) in
    if let data = response.data as? [GApiResponse.NearBy], response.isValidFor(.nearBy){
        // all nearby places
    }
}
```

Interesting part is I added a bonus api to get all the 60 nearby places so the user don't have to worry about the next page token and call the api till the final result come. Here is an example to get all the result.

```
var input = GInput()
input.keyword = "Restaurants"
input.radius = 20000
var location = GLocation()
location.latitude = 26.273178
location.longitude = 73.009545
input.destinationCoordinate = location
NearbyExtension.shared.completion = { response in
    if let data = response.data as? [GApiResponse.NearBy], response.isValidFor(.nearBy){
        // all nearby places
    }
}
NearbyExtension.shared.getAllNearBy(input: input)
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example url, where it returns a list of starbucks near your location.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=(yourlatitude),(yourlongitude)&radius=5000&keyword=starbucks&key=(yourkey)

You can get the key from google console

Answer (score 3):

Check this out -->>
https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial

"Finding Something to Eat" section have what you needs.

Comment: But there again, stuff is displayed on a MapView... :/

Comment: @Janninho Dude, that tutorial will help u learn how to integrate Google Places and how to receive the results containing the nearby places. From there on, you can go ahead and learn how to display things to a tableview instead. You can't expect a tutorial to have exactly what you need.