# Swift, take places near user position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

i'm a beginner in developing an i'm adding a google map on a view of my application, following a tutorial i used this code

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
            print("Location: \(location)")

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                                  longitude: location.coordinate.longitude,
                                                  zoom: zoomlevel)


            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.title = "My Position"

            marker.map = mapView
            if mapView.isHidden {
                mapView.isHidden = false
                mapView.camera = camera
            } else {
                mapView.animate(to: camera)
            }


        }


        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            switch status {
            case .restricted:
                print("Location access was restricted.")
            case .denied:
                print("User denied access to location.")

                mapView.isHidden = false
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Location status not determined.")
            case .authorizedAlways: fallthrough
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("Location status is OK.")
            }
        }


        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
```

to find the user location, now i would like to see on the map the places (google places) that are on a X distance from the user position, how can i do it? i searched on the google places doc but not find a valid answer

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333550/get-list-of-nearby-places-from-google-places-api-swift-3] ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another marker onTap on mapView and make it draggable and use CLLocationDistance to measure distance between 2 locations.

```
let distanceInMeters = self.locationManager.location?.distance(from: newMarkerLocation!)
```