# Get places in location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager

I'm getting city and country information from latitude, longitude. But I want a list of nearby restaurants, hospitals etc. i.e.the complete list of places as listed [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) so that I can show them on a tableview.

Also how can I get the list of just the restaurants (say) on the map...?

Comment: pass parameter type= restaurant as per the docs

Comment: ok @Scriptable..can u tell me where I can find the docs..? Also how can I get the entire list of places together..?

Comment: see: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333550/get-list-of-nearby-places-from-google-places-api-swift-3 probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, where it returns a list of restaurant nearby the location specified in the URL.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=YOUR_LATITUDE,YOUR_LONGITUDE&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can get the key from google console. For more help you can refer google doc

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

> Your Alamofire Request Will be like :

```
let headers = [
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            ]

let req = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON
            {
                (responseData:DataResponse<Any>) in
                //Handle your response Here
            }
```

Comment: ok @Shruti Thombre. THanks..But the url that u have provided..should I use it as a normal api call...?

Comment: @user308123 yes..You can use it like normal API call

Comment: ok @Shruti Thombre. Then in that case, what will be the parameters and headers (if I'm making an Alamofire request)..?

Comment: @user308123 hope this is helpful for you?

Comment: I was just trying it @Shruti Thombre...will update soon...:)

Comment: Thanks @Shruti Thombre 6 hours ago